# How to use the usePermissions React-Admin hook correctly to restrict access to resources?

Tags: react-admin, user-permissions

I'm trying to make a distinction in the UI to resources based on the roles obtained from the usePermissions hook.
This is my App component:

```
import * as React from "react";
...
const store = localStorageStore();

function App() {
  return (
    <AdminContext
      authProvider={authProvider}
      dataProvider={CabDataProvider}
      i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
      store={store}
    >
      <AsyncResources />
    </AdminContext>
  );
}

interface CabDataProvider extends DataProvider {
  getResources: () => Promise<{ name: string }[]>;
}

function AsyncResources() {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState<Array<{ name: string }>>(
    [] as Array<{ name: string }>
  );
  const dataProvider = useDataProvider<CabDataProvider>();

  useEffect(() => {
    dataProvider.getResources().then((r) => setResources(r));
  }, []);

  const { isLoading, permissions } = usePermissions();

  if (isLoading == false) {
    console.log(permissions);
    return (
      <AdminUI ready={Loading} loginPage={CabLogin} dashboard={Dashboard}>
      {permissions.role === "admin" ? (
        <Resource
          name="users"
          create={UserCreate}
          list={UsersList}
          edit={UserEdit}
        />
      ) : null}
        <Resource name="offices" list={OfficesList} />
        <CustomRoutes noLayout>
          <Route path="/registration" element={<CabRegistration />} />
        </CustomRoutes>
      </AdminUI>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AdminUI ready={Loading} loginPage={CabLogin} dashboard={Dashboard}>
      </AdminUI>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

My getPermissions method in authProvider

```
getPermissions: () => {
    try {
      const role = localStorage.getItem("role" as string)?.replace(/"/g, ""),
        permissions = localStorage.getItem("permissions" as string)?.replace(/"/g, "");
      return Promise.resolve({ role, permissions });
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject({ message: "Failed to retrieve permissions", error });
    }
  }
```

**permissions.role** is **undefined** after authorization. The desired value is obtained only after the browser page is reloaded.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: usePermissions calls authProvider.getPermissions. What your authProvider.getPermissions returns ? Are there any requests in the Network tab?

Comment: Here is my getPermissions in authProvider:
<code>getPermissions: () => {
    try {
      const role = localStorage.getItem("role" as string)?.replace(/"/g, ""),
        permissions = localStorage.getItem("permissions" as string)?.replace(/"/g, "");
      return Promise.resolve({ role, permissions });
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject({ message: "Failed to retrieve permissions", error });
    }
  }</code>
The data gets to localStorage immediately after authorization. I see them in the Application -> Local Storage tab

Comment: Not really sure why your current code doesn't work. But I see you are kind of mixing [declaring resources at runtime](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#unplugging-the-admin-using-admincontext-and-adminui) and [using permissions to restrict access to resources](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Permissions.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views), although you seem to be only needing the latter. If that is the case, you should probably implement the solution provided in this doc I linked instead, as it is much simpler.